# How to select a specific entire colum of a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a QTableView with three columns like the example below:

|   **Id**    |    **name**    |    **ACoord**    |

I am trying to highlight the entire ACoord column no matter which cell I am clicking on in the ACoord only.

I have tried several examples but nothing is helpful.
The most promising (also from official QT documentation) seems to be `setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectColumns)` but didn't work exactly as I need.

Here is the snipped of code:

```
connect(mTurnIntoExcelData, &QAction::triggered, [&]() {
        int row = -1, column = -1;
        QString reference;
        QString type;
        QModelIndex index;
        int rowModel = index.row();
        SelectionData currentData;

        for(int i = 0; i < ui->tableViewLeft->model()->columnCount(); i++)
        {
          if(ui->tableViewLeft->model()->headerData(i, Qt::Horizontal).toString() == "ACoord") {
              column = i;
              ui->tableViewLeft->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectColumns);
              ui->tableViewLeft->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
              type = "ACoord";
      }
```

The expected result is: I click on any cell of the ACoord and the entire column becomes selectable.

However, the actual result is that if I click on any cell of ACoord column I am not able to select the entire column, but only the single cell.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most elegant way to do it, but I was able to get (what I believe is) the behavior you want by modifying Qt's "FrozenColumn" example program (in $QTDIR/qtbase/examples/widgets/itemviews/frozencolumn) in the following way:

In `freezetablewidget.h`, add the following declarations inside the `private slots:` section:

```
void currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &);  
void autoSelectMagicColumn();
```

In `freezetablewidget.cpp`, add a `#include <QTimer>` to the includes-section at the top, then add the following lines to the end of the `FreezeTableWidget::init()` method:

```
connect(frozenTableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &)));
connect(frozenTableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &)));  // optional
```

... and finally, add the following new lines into `freezetablewidget.cpp`:

```
const int magicColumnIndex = 2;  // or whichever column you want the auto-selecting to happen on

void FreezeTableWidget::currentColumnChanged(const QModelIndex & mi)
{
   const int col = mi.column();
   if (col == magicColumnIndex)
   {
      // Auto-select the entire column!  (Gotta schedule it be done later 
      //  since it doesn't work if I just call selectColumn() directly at this point)
      QTimer::singleShot(100, this, SLOT(autoSelectMagicColumn()));
   }
}

void FreezeTableWidget::autoSelectMagicColumn()
{
    // Double-check that the focus is still on the magic column index, in case the user moves fast
    if (selectionModel()->currentIndex().column() == magicColumnIndex) frozenTableView->selectColumn(magicColumnIndex);
}
```

With the above changes, the FrozenColumn example app will auto-select the entire "YDS" column whenever I click on any cell in that column (or navigate to any cell in that column via the arrow keys).  Perhaps you can do something similar in your program.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that worked fine! Exactly what I was looking for and actually adding a timer it is a good idea.